# ActiveMQ Loadbalance and HA

Tags: activemq-classic, master-slave, messagebroker

We're looking to employ ActiveM with Mule ESB. Our premise for ActiveMQ is to design loadbalanced HA architecture. As such, we're looking at:
1. Using 2 Masters (M1 and M2) and Slaves (S1 and S2). Each broker instance will be networked with each other.
2. M1 and S1 will share the same filesystem as will M2 and S2 for failover.

A. Would this be the correct approach?
B. How do I change the persistence adapter in the activemq.xml file to reflect the NFS mount point shared between M1 and S1 and M2 and S2? Do I create a properties file or just change to
    
             
    
Thanks!

Comment: While the approach is indeed a good one, I would insist on studying the mechanics of ActiveMQ a bit more before you do such a thing. Still - there is more to it than changing the path to the kahadb folder.

Comment: Thanks petter - Looking for any docs that can point to more than changing the kahadb folder. - What else would there be?